# Diff in PhpStorm

Tags: diff, phpstorm

How can I compare a document in the current project with one that is not part of the project?
How can I compare two arbitrary files on my computer with phpStorm?

Comment: You could copy the content from the external file into clipboard and right click on/in your project file and then click `Compare with clipboard`.

Comment: @Dan Lee Yes, as you mentioned currently easiest way that I found for comparing a project file with a non-project file is copy external file to clipboard and select "View->Compare with clipboard".

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Currently, the easiest way that I found to compare a project file with a non-project file is by copying the external file to the clipboard and clicking on "View-> Compare with clipboard".

Comment: For me this feature is broken in version phpstorm 10. Someone experiencing the same?

Answer (score 8):

It can be done only externally:

You can also open the difference viewer without running PhpStorm. This is done through the following command:

```
<path to PhpStorm executable file> diff <path_1> <path_2>
```

where `path_1` and `path_2` are paths to the files in question, which can be of various types, including jar.

From inside PhpStorm you can only compare files that are available in the project.

Answer (score 2):

What I do for comparing two external sources (web page sources etc.)

1 - Open a new scratch file from "File" Menu -> "New Scratch File" and choose a file type

2 - Copy & Paste Source 1 to this new scratch file

3 - Either create a new scratch file for second source and click "Compare With" from "View" Menu 
or 
better just directly copy second to clipboard and from "View" Menu click to "Compare with Clipboard"

Answer (score 2):

#### MacOS

Create a file in `/usr/local/bin/` named **PhpStorm**

Paste this

```
#!/bin/sh

open -na "PhpStorm.app" --args "$@"
```

And make it executable

```
chmod +x /usr/local/bin/PhpStorm
```

And now you can do this

```
PhpStorm diff <path1> <path2>
```

#### Windows

Add PhpStorm bin to your PATH

```
setx PATH=%PATH%;C:\Program Files\JetBrains\PhpStorm\bin
```

Now you can do this

```
phpstorm.bat diff <path1> <path2>
```

#### Linux

Create a link to your PhpStorm launcher script :

```
# Path to PhpStorm installation may differ
ln -s /opt/phpstorm/bin/phpstorm.sh /usr/local/bin/phpstorm
```

Now you can do

```
phpstorm diff <path1> <path2>
```

---

Sources from jetbrains werbsite :

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/command-line-differences-viewer.html

https://www.jetbrains.com/help/phpstorm/working-with-the-ide-features-from-command-line.html

Answer (score 0):

In phpStorm 2016.2 (and possibly some earlier editions) you can navigate to the external file via File >> Open... , which will open a tab showing the external file's content. You can then use View>> Compare with... to compare the external file to a file within your project.