# Track but don't stage files with git?

Tags: git, phpstorm

I have a lot of untracked styles. I want to add them to the changes that GIT is aware of but are not staged for commit.

My reason is that my IDE has git integration and I want to view the diffs with this. If the changes are untracked I'm not able to diff them. using git add . is very time consuming as I then need to unstage the changes repeatedly.

Comment: You could use `git diff` to see the difference between your files and staging area.

Comment: I want to use my IDE for the diff not the command line.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12365086/diff-in-phpstorm

Comment: http://blog.jetbrains.com/webide/2013/02/comparing-files-and-folders-within-your-ide/

Comment: `git add --intent-to-add`

Comment: git add --intent-to-add does not work. It stages the change to be committed.

Comment: You want to have the files tracked, but you don't want them to be staged.  Not sure that's possible considering that in order for a file to become tracked, it first must be staged.

Answer (score 0):

If your reason to not stage the files is to see the diff, you can parameterize the diff command, as explained in [How do I show the changes which have been staged?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1587846/how-do-i-show-the-changes-which-have-been-staged)